# Android Crashlytics issue with JetPack Jetifier

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, crashlytics, android-jetpack

Well I created a project and added the `Fabric` plugin and `Crashlytics` dependency and I also tested it and it worked. But when I refactor the project to use `AndroidX` and enable the jetifier tool `android.enableJetifier=true` the project wont build and I get multiple errors like:

`Failed to transform file 'crashlytics-2.9.2.aar' to match attributes {artifactType=jetified-aar} using transform JetifyTransform`

It seems there is something wrong with `jetifier` tool and the `Crashlytics` dependency. Is there a way to turn off the `JetifyTransform` for a single dependency?

Project level gradle file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.41'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-alpha14'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.2'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Module level gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'android-P'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ir.scannpay.person"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0-alpha1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha1'

    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.2'
}
```

gradle.properties file:

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```

And I didn't forget to put the `Fabric` key in the `manifest`, I also put the `google-services.json` file in `app` module.

When I try to build, I get multiple of these errors:

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Failed to transform file 'crashlytics-2.9.2.aar' to match attributes {artifactType=jetified-aar} using transform JetifyTransform

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Failed to transform file 'crashlytics-core-2.6.2.aar' to match attributes {artifactType=jetified-aar} using transform JetifyTransform

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Failed to transform file 'beta-1.2.7.aar' to match attributes {artifactType=jetified-aar} using transform JetifyTransform
```

Comment: Check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50270599/failed-to-transform-error-after-migrating-to-androidx/50318561

Comment: @MohammadTabbara alright thanks. Well when I turn the jetifier off the project builds. I hoped there was a way to turn it off only for a specific dependency.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well I found the solution.

What you need to do is to upgrade your fabric version to `1.25.4` in your project level `build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4'
    }
}
```

Comment: Also make sure to check https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/androidx-rn for release notes.