# Failed to transform after moving to AndroidX

Tags: android, androidx

I have 3 versions of my project in my IDE Android studio. version 4, version 6 and version 7.
I updated my IDE from ArcticFox to Giraffe the other week and it broke my projects. In the end i deleted the IDE and re-installed ArticFox. Version 7 did used to work prior to moving to giraffe and back to articFox again, so not sure what has changed.

Version 4 and version 6 work fine but version 7 does not. In version 7 i moved away from the appCompt library and i now use AndroidX.

I get the following when trying to run the app.

```
Failed to transform 'C:\Users\mattheww\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\androidx.activity\activity\1.6.0\4bee9777c02790cb99e68cd397036b1d5508a630\activity-1.6.0.aar' using Jetifier. Reason: null. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.) To disable Jetifier, set android.enableJetifier=false in your gradle.properties file.
```

What i have tried:

['Failed to transform" error after migrating to AndroidX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50270599/failed-to-transform-error-after-migrating-to-androidx)

i tried amending android.enableJetifier=true by setting it to false in the gradle file and also setting the following on the  tag in manifest - tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory

i don't seem to have any reference to the old appCompat libray anywhere either.

Is there anything else i can try?

here is my gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'


    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.rr3"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionName "7.0"
        setProperty("archivesBaseName", "RR7v$versionName" + "DEV")
        multiDexEnabled true

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
            multiDexKeepProguard file('multidex-config.pro')
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'

    compile files('libs/activation.jar')
    compile files('libs/additionnal.jar')
    //compile files('libs/core.jar')
    compile files('libs/mail.jar')
    compile files('libs/ndeftools-1.2.3.jar')




    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.8.4'


    implementation 'joda-time:joda-time:2.1'
    implementation 'net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:4.5.4@aar'

    implementation 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'

    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'



    implementation('com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.6.0') { transitive = false }
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.github.florent37:singledateandtimepicker:2.1.4' //https://github.com/florent37/SingleDateAndTimePicker
    implementation 'androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.1'


}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
```

[Update 1]

i have tried the following:

gradlew clean :app:processDebugResources

the output is:

```
* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Failed to transform file 'activity-1.6.0.aar' to match attributes {artifactType=processed-aar} using transform JetifyTransform
   > Failed to transform 'C:\Users\mattheww\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\androidx.activity\activity\1.6.0\4bee9777c02790cb99e68cd397036b1d5508a630\activity-1.6.0.aar' using Jetifier. Reason: null. (Run with --stackt
race for more details.) To disable Jetifier, set android.enableJetifier=false in your gradle.properties file.
> Failed to transform file 'activity-1.6.0.aar' to match attributes {artifactType=processed-aar} using transform JetifyTransform
   > Failed to transform 'C:\Users\mattheww\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\androidx.activity\activity\1.6.0\4bee9777c02790cb99e68cd397036b1d5508a630\activity-1.6.0.aar' using Jetifier. Reason: null. (Run with --stackt
race for more details.) To disable Jetifier, set android.enableJetifier=false in your gradle.properties file.
> Failed to transform file 'activity-1.6.0.aar' to match attributes {artifactType=processed-aar} using transform JetifyTransform
   > Failed to transform 'C:\Users\mattheww\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\androidx.activity\activity\1.6.0\4bee9777c02790cb99e68cd397036b1d5508a630\activity-1.6.0.aar' using Jetifier. Reason: null. (Run with --stackt
race for more details.) To disable Jetifier, set android.enableJetifier=false in your gradle.properties file.
> Failed to transform file 'annotation-experimental-1.3.0.aar' to match attributes {artifactType=processed-aar} using transform JetifyTransform
   > Failed to transform 'C:\Users\mattheww\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\androidx.annotation\annotation-experimental\1.3.0\5087c6f545117dcd474e69e1a93cacec9d7334af\annotation-experimental-1.3.0.aar' using Jetifier.
Reason: null. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.) To disable Jetifier, set android.enableJetifier=false in your gradle.properties file.
> Failed to transform file 'annotation-experimental-1.3.0.aar' to match attributes {artifactType=processed-aar} using transform JetifyTransform
   > Failed to transform 'C:\Users\mattheww\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\androidx.annotation\annotation-experimental\1.3.0\5087c6f545117dcd474e69e1a93cacec9d7334af\annotation-experimental-1.3.0.aar' using Jetifier.
Reason: null. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.) To disable Jetifier, set android.enableJetifier=false in your gradle.properties file.
> Failed to transform file 'annotation-experimental-1.3.0.aar' to match attributes {artifactType=processed-aar} using transform JetifyTransform
   > Failed to transform 'C:\Users\mattheww\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\androidx.annotation\annotation-experimental\1.3.0\5087c6f545117dcd474e69e1a93cacec9d7334af\annotation-experimental-1.3.0.aar' using Jetifier.
Reason: null. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.) To disable Jetifier, set android.enableJetifier=false in your gradle.properties file.
> Failed to transform file 'annotation-experimental-1.3.0.aar' to match attributes {artifactType=processed-aar} using transform JetifyTransform
   > Failed to transform 'C:\Users\mattheww\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\androidx.annotation\annotation-experimental\1.3.0\5087c6f545117dcd474e69e1a93cacec9d7334af\annotation-experimental-1.3.0.aar' using Jetifier.
Reason: null. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.) To disable Jetifier, set android.enableJetifier=false in your gradle.properties file.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

[update 2]

i'm using the following gradle

[image]

[update 3]

i've update gradle tools version to 8.1.1 and i getthe following.

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:92)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl$2.run(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:204)
    at org.gradle.configuration.ProjectScriptTarget.addConfiguration(ProjectScriptTarget.java:77)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:209)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.run(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:61)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:317)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:309)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:185)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:97)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.apply(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:58)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:41)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:26)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:34)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.doConfigure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:66)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.access$100(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:37)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$ConfigureProject.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:125)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:317)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:309)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:185)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:97)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:677)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:138)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:35)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:62)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:41)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$ConfigureBuild.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:262)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:317)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:309)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:185)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:97)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.configureBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:175)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:132)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:115)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:77)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:74)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:152)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:96)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:74)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.java:61)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:317)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:309)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:185)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:97)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:51)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:65)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:82)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:295)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/build/gradle/AppPlugin has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2199)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3934)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3938)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4821)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginRegistry.uncheckedGet(DefaultPluginRegistry.java:149)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginRegistry.lookup(DefaultPluginRegistry.java:144)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginRegistry.lookup(DefaultPluginRegistry.java:127)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginRegistry.lookup(DefaultPluginRegistry.java:121)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.apply(DefaultPluginManager.java:120)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.applyType(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:120)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.access$200(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction$3.run(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:86)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.execute(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:143)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractPluginAware.apply(AbstractPluginAware.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ProjectScript.apply(ProjectScript.java:34)
    at org.gradle.api.Script$apply.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at build_aji68kjhfk0uu807zdhtb8ruq.run(C:\Users\Matt\Source_Code\RR7.0\RR6v6.1AS\RR6v6.1AS\nfcscanner3\app\build.gradle:1)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:90)
    ... 102 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/build/gradle/AppPlugin has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginRegistry$1.load(DefaultPluginRegistry.java:71)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginRegistry$1.load(DefaultPluginRegistry.java:51)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3524)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2317)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2280)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2195)
    ... 119 more
```

Also thses are already set to true in my project.

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```

I don't use the following.

```
classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove Multidex:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
```

Source: https://developer.android.com/build/multidex#mdex-on-l

It might be messing with AndroidX. I also suggest checking other libraries and updating them or temporarily disabling them to find out which one is causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

It might not be an elegant solution but consider creating a new project in giraffe and copying your Java/Kotlin files from the old project to the new one.

Structure of some of the gradle files have changed in newer gradle versions.

Comment: i may have to do this on another machine. i dare not change the IDE again on this machine as it has production code on it and we are due a new release soon

Answer (score 0):

First of all try deleting Gradle caches of dependencies. Which are stored in the folder:

```
/Users/mattheww/.gradle/module-2.
```

After deleting the module-2 folder, upgrade you dependencies in Android Studio project. Then add these lines which sets Java version for your project:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
 }
```

Then rebuild project. Make sure you have an active Internet connection and a cup of Cofee. Because it will take time for downloading dependencies as we have removed all.

I Hope this might help...

Comment: will this affect other projects in the IDE?

Comment: Unfortunately it will. because module-2 contains cached data of Dependencies related to all projects.

Comment: It will effect in a way that you have to download again those. Gradle will do this automatically. You don't have to do anything much.

Comment: ah ok, can't do that then as this IDE has the 2 previous version of production software.  version 5 is in production right now. We are due to release version 6 in the coming weeks. both projects compile in the IDE now. Version 7 is the version that does not as i migrated to androidX from 6 to 7. I think i will download the latest android studio on a different machine and try to get 7 working. If not i can try version 6 on new machine and go through the androidX migration again

Answer (score -1):

There are four ways to solve the error for Failed to transform after moving to AndroidX.

```
 1. Update some dependencies in build.gradle file.

i.e. change

classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.1'

 to

classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.27.0'
```

2. Add below line in gradle.properties file:

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```

3. Change build.gradle(:app) file

```
sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6

to

sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
```

4. update your tool version in build.gradle file

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.1'
```

Comment: hi, i've edited the post. please see update 3

Comment: Please add below code after android{ ..........} may be it work for you      allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots' }
        jcenter()
    }
}